# Ext.define doesn't work in app.js (onReady)

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm nebew in sencha touch. I'm trying to use Ext.define in app.js, but did not work. First I tried with Ext.data.Model, but only worked when I created a file (using sencha cmd). Now I'm trying with Ext.dataview.component.DataItem. How I supposed to do?

```
Ext.define('MyDataItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    alias: 'widget.mydataitem',
    config: {
        padding: 10,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        defaults: {
            margin: 5
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Val1'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            flex: 1,
            html: 'val2',
            itemId: 'textCmp'
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: if I try
    var temp = Ext.create('mydataitem');
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading synchronously via XHR: 'mydataitem.js'; please verify that the file exists. XHR status code: 404

Or
Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got undefined
when using in Ext.dataview.DataView

Comment: var filterMenuItemsDataView = Ext.create('Ext.dataview.DataView', {
        defaultType: 'mydataitem',
        useComponents: true,
        layout: 'fit',
        store: {
            data: [{
                val1: 'A Button',
                val2: 'with text'
                }, {
                val1: 'The Button',
                val2: 'more text'
                }, {
                val1: 'My Button',
                val2: 'My Text'
                }],
                model: 'adjustPrice.model.TestModel'
            },
            emptyText: 'Your cart is empty',
    });

Comment: As you are not showing the full code, this is a bit tricky. Did you add Ext.dataview.DataView to the requires part of the app.js?